# Decentralised management of multiple objects?

Tags: algorithm

There is a tunnel in which there are various kinds of obstacles (the letters T or just partition and the other). Also, there are some objects that fly through this tunnel. The world itself is subject to the most simple physics. The task to write algorithm for decentralized management of these objects to bypass obstacles.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKGNK.png)

Suitable for whether this Boids algorithm, or there is something else? The theory would also be welcome.

Comment: im unclear what you mean by 'decentralized' here.

Comment: It consists of a plurality of agents , locally and interacting with the environment. Agents themselves are simple, but all together , locally interacting, creating the so-called It called RI ( in nature - a colony of ants , swarm of bees , a flock of birds , fish , etc. ) .

Answer (score 0):

A boids algorithm should work. I have not done anything with a tunnel, but I have had boids avoid obstacles and seek goals. [Here](https://github.com/FakeNameSE/Boids-with-obstacles-and-goals) is a link a repo with an implementation of boids in python.

The gist of the obstacle avoidance portion is that if there is an obstacle within a certain distance, the boid calculated a vector toward that object (x would be `object.x - boid.x` and same for y), multiply the vector by -1, divide this vector by a coefficient (the value depends on your other coefficients) and then add this vector to your total movement vector of the boid.

I hope this helped!